jq returns command not found with the right result
Running the following statement:
CLUSTER_IP=$(kubectl get svc blue -o json | jq '.spec.clusterIP'
Then to see the value by typing the following:
$CLUSTER_IP
Returns:

"10.96.210.135": command not found

I cant use the variable in a bash statement.
Am I missing something in the statement?

what about using echo $CLUSTER_IP to "see the value"? since $CLUSTER_IP is the result of that command, it won't likely be a command, but some value that you want to use some how

when I run echo $CLUSTER_IP it shows only the IP correctly but using the variable in a statement like this "for i in $(seq 10); do curl http://$CLUSTER_IP; done" statement fails curl: (3) url rejected bad hostname whereas when I issue direct assignment  $CLUSTER_IP="1.96....." thye statement works fine

because "10.96.210.135" is not a valid hostname. Use jq -r to strip the quotes.

Thanks Gerald, I added the -r flag, when I issued  $CLUSTER_IP it also showed the IP appended to it "command not found" but the bash statement that do the curl went through this time successfully

This would have been way easier if you had stated directly that you have a problem with curl instead of complaining that your shell refuses to execute an IP address as a command. Which, of course, will not work.

How to remove double-quotes in jq output for parsing json files in bash? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656515/how-to-remove-double-quotes-in-jq-output-for-parsing-json-files-in-bash

Sorry Gerald, maybe I was not so clear but I stated "I cant use the variable in a bash statement"

You can and you used it successfully. curl uses the variable, which is evident from its error message. The problem is not that you can't use the variable, but that the variable itself contains an invalid value, it's "10.96.210.135" instead of 10.96.210.135 which you have when you "issue direct assignment". These quotes you see are the part of the value and they make the IP address invalid, because the valid IP address value won't contain quotes, and it causes curl to err out. Your jq command returns the value with quotes for some reason, and you need to get rid of these.
